# Slingshot delay and other apps (Loki)

Tags: release-loki, slingshot, nvidia

I have a Dell XPS L502X Nvidia and Intel video cards.

I'm not sure if this a Nvidia/Nouveau issue but Slingshot menu always has a delay. Usually after the second try it works fairly fast again, but if I click it again after a few minutes the delay comes back.

I had Nvidia-361 installed the issue was there. I did a clean install of Loki but this time with Nouveau drivers and have the same issue.

Is anyone going through this, and if so is there a solution?

Comment: I got the same problem in freya, was hoping it will get solved in loki but seems like not :(

Comment: I've also noticed that slingshot is 1. noticeably slower than other launchers, 2. inconsistent in its speed (sometimes it gets particularly slow). I believe it's just the app, not your drivers.

Comment: I was afraid of that

Comment: Definitely not just the drivers. Same problem here on a Dell Inspiron 15 5559 with Intel Skylake i7 / AMD Radeon R5 M335 graphics

Comment: How can I (or someone else) file a bug for this?

Comment: In Launchpad. See here: https://launchpad.net/elementary there is a tab for bugs. I just filed our problem there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1625775

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to this.

Open terminal and type

> **cd /usr/bin**
>
> **sudo mv zeitgeist-daemon zeitgeist-daemon.bak**
>
> **sudo reboot**

I noticed the **Zeitgeist-daemon** was affecting my **Slingshot**. On the **downside** if you have to use **Security & Privacy on Switchboard it wont open**. You would **need** to launch **zeitgeist-daemon.bak** first and then try to open it.

By disabling zeitgeist-daemon, the **first time** you open Slingshot will fill a bit **slow** but then after that it will **always** work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution.

There is a Slingshot Launcher fork call **Panther Launcher**. It looks and works exactly the same.

It is faster and it does not depend on Gala or Granite.

> **http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/panther_launcher.html**

Download the **Ubuntu 64 bit** version and install it.

Then open **System Settings - Desktop - Hot Corners**

Select the **top left corner** and choose **Execute Custom Command** and set it to

> **panther_launcher**

Then go back to **System Settings - Keyboard - Custom** and add a new shortcut.

The **first time** you launch Panther **might freeze** but try again and it will work just fine after.

If you want to customize the amount of columns, icon size, etc. Open **Dconf-editor** and go to

> **org.rastersoft.panther**

Once you finish customizing you need to **kill** Panthern and launch it again.

> **killall panther_launcher**

So far this is the best solution for me, I don't know why but Slingshot it is very laggy and I would love to use it by default.